# Dynamic width for a Bootstrap panel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two panels: the first one is the main panel, the second one is nested within that first panel.

[image]

I want to get rid of that empty space without setting a fixed width for that second, grey panel. In other words, to make the grey panel's width dynamic. How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide some jsfiddle or code you have tried , that will help to solve your problem in a better way .

Comment: My bad, I thought the setup would be simple enough to understand. The original code is a little messy cos it's a Django HTML template.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block` to your inner panel.  Here's a fiddle showing it:

https://jsfiddle.net/5fct62u1/

Comment: It's not a working solution. It works for text-only panels, but on panels with an image inside them the image gets scaled down proportionally too. The point is for the width to be shortened depending on the amount of text, but leaving the image size intact.